# Weird behavior with SwiftUI animation and scaleEffect

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am experiencing some weird UI behaviors when trying to change the scale of scaleEffect while a repeatForever easeInOut animation is happening.

**Expected behavior:** each time the circle is clicked, the pulsate animation will alternate between large pulsate animation (same interval, but bigger circles) and smaller pulsate animation (same interval, but smaller circles).

**Actual behavior:** After the second time the circle is clicked, the pulsating animation is no longer the normal easInOut animation (looked like it had a stroke), but the animation becomes erratic and looked like multiple pulsating animations overlayed on top of each other.

Any ideas on why this is happening? And how to fix it?

Here is the code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatedView: View {
    let scale: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: scale)
    }
}

struct TestAnimation: View {
    @State private var large_pulsate: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        AnimatedView(scale: large_pulsate ? 2.0 : 1.1)
            .onTapGesture {
                large_pulsate.toggle()
            }
    }
}

struct TestAnimation_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestAnimation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, your circle initially does not pulsate. Is that intended?

Comment: Sorry, it's not intended. But for the sake of this question, you can assume it's not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SwiftUI animation happens between two view states: the *before* state and the *after* state.  The way you have it coded now, you are not explicitly controlling those two states.  The end result is that you are getting multiple animations on the same view.

By sending both scales to the `AnimatedView`, the animated view can fully control its animation by starting with `scale1` (establishing the *before* state), and then change to its animated state by setting `animating` to `true` and then using `scale2` (establishing the *after* state).  This will ensure that the animation takes place between `scale1` and `scale2`.

```
struct AnimatedView: View {
    let scale1: CGFloat
    let scale2: CGFloat
    @State private var animating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .scaleEffect(animating ? scale2 : scale1)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animating)
            .onAppear {
                animating = true
            }
    }
}

struct TestAnimation: View {
    @State private var large_pulsate: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimatedView(scale1: large_pulsate ? 2.0 : 1.1, scale2: large_pulsate ? 1.1 : 2.0)
            .onTapGesture {
                large_pulsate.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

---

### A Better Solution

The answer above always animates.  If you wanted to wait until the first click to start animation, then you could pass a value to indicate the the view should be animated.  Then the `AnimatedView` would switch to the second value only when `animated` is `true`.

Also, we want to enforce `AnimatedView` to be recreated each time the view is tapped.  This will ensure the animation gets recreated with a new view.  To do this, add an `.id()` to the `AnimatedView` and give that a new `UUID` each time the view is tapped.

```
struct AnimatedView: View {
    let scale1: CGFloat
    let scale2: CGFloat
    let animated: Bool
    @State private var animating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .scaleEffect(animating ? scale2 : scale1)
            .animation(Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animating)
            .onAppear {
                if animated {
                    animating = true
                }
            }
            
    }
}

struct TestAnimation: View {
    @State private var large_pulsate: Bool = false
    @State private var animated = false  // no animation until first tap
    @State private var vid = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimatedView(scale1: 1.0, scale2: large_pulsate ? 2.0 : 0.5, animated: animated)
            .onTapGesture {
                large_pulsate.toggle()
                animated = true
                vid = UUID()  // ensures a new AnimatedView is created
            }
            .id(vid)
           
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the second solution, but for some reason when you click to toggle nothing happens, the pulsation stays at the same size. Do you know where is the issue?

Comment: Hmmm.  I just retested it using the code I posted and it works.  Which version of Xcode are you using?  What is the version of iOS are you testing with?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 14.3.1 with iPhone 14 Pro simulator (both 16.4 and 17.0).